# Where to keep gwt-dispatch classes?

Tags: gwt, command-pattern, gwt-dispatch

Where gwt-dispatcher classes (Action, Result, Handler) should be kept? I mean it should be all in client package or maybe shared or any other combination? How do You handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a small app called [SixFixMix](http://code.google.com/p/sixfixmix/) and in there, here's what I do:

- Action/Result classes are kept in a ...shared.rpc package
- Handler classes are kept in a ...server.handler package